# Занимаюсь НА или В спортгородке?

Tags: предлоги

Спортгородок - это брусья и турник, например.

Answer (score 2):

Городок, спортгородок. ***Где? В городке, в спортгородке.*** Думаю, что говорить нужно именно так.

Ср.: ***занимаюсь на брусьях, на турнике.***

Пример из Нацкорпуса: *Бадминтон, мини-футбол, шахматы, шашки, настольный теннис ежедневно с 10.00 до 19.00 в спортгородке.* [ Афиша // «Столица», 1997.07.15]